# Besides binary, decimal, hex, oct, are there encryption algorithms based on exotic/other numbering systems?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

We all know there is Base 10, Base 16, etc. Are there encryption algorithms out there based on different or unique Base-N numbering systems?

Comment: Note that different bases do nothing for security; FF1 and FF3 basically take a base 2 algorithm (computers work on bits) and convert it so it can be used on different input / output domains. FF1 and FF3 are handy if your input / output needs to be in a particular range - the algorithm itself of course still works using bit operations. You can also use e.g. base64 on the ciphertext if your output should adhere to a specific range of printable characters.

Answer (score 3):

There's [FF1 and FF3](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38G.pdf), which are Format Preserving Encryption methods that can use an arbitrary base internally.  This can be useful, for example, if you are encrypting a fixed length alphanumeric field, it would make sense to use base 36 (radix=36) or base 62 (if upper and lower cases are distinguished).